# how to maintain focus between two screen component?

Tags: android, android-activity, focus, android-fragments

In my two screen app first screen has some button, from here control jump to other activity. Now when control return to first activity from second, how can focus for last action item?

Also please suggest how can do same thing while communicating between two fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `requestFocus()` on the control in your first activity's `onResume()` method?

If you need to remember which control was tapped (and therefore which one should have focus), you can save a reference to in whatever code starts the second activity (such as that control's `OnClickListener`), and use that information in `onResume()`.

Comment: thanks for your response...yes it can work in case of activity navigation.Do u have idea how it will work in fragment navigation.

Comment: It depends on how you're using your fragments (such as whether the two fragments can be visible at the same time, and how your app transitions between them), but the same general principle should still work, as fragments have very similar lifecycle methods to activities.

Comment: Thanks ..in my case at a time one fragment is visible and from here control navigate to second fragment and again back to first one...any suggestion?